# Recycle Bin acquires thousands of files

Tags: windows-7, internet, internet-explorer, recycle-bin

I am using a stand-alone PC desktop computer with Win 7. When computer slows down, I find that the recycle bin has thousands of files. Most recently, 18,200+ files. I empty it. Most files are .gif - It's like every picture I click on in Internet Explores sends a deleted copy to the Recycle Bin, though many .gifs do not show the picture. Probably a setting somewhere. What do I do?

Comment: What is Exactly your Question?

Comment: @AmirrezaNasiri - Really? You can't understand the question from this?

Comment: Do you have any file clean up or cache monitoring services installed? Does the issue also occur in safe mode (where no plugins are running)

Answer (score 1):

I've been using the [Sysinternals suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062) for diagnosing weird Windows behavior. Process Explorer alone makes the usual Task Manager look like a joke :) And it's free, and from Microsoft, so it's definitely good to have lying around.

If no one knows what can cause your problem off the top of their head, I'd recommend digging into it with the Process Monitor (procmon).

1. Start up procmon, and brace yourself for a massive flood of data!
2. Figure out and set a filter that will show you stuff going to the Recycle Bin. I'd create and delete a dummy file to see what that looks like in procmon, and then base the filter on the result.
3. Restart procmon's monitoring to get rid of the stuff that's accumulated since you launched it.
4. Use your computer as you normally would until you see some lines with GIFs going to the Recycle Bin in procmon.
5. Highlight one of those lines and disable your filter (bracing yourself again!).
6. Check the surrounding lines for clues as to why those GIFs are getting dumped there. You may need to add a few filters to silence stuff you don't care about. My Symantec antivirus is particularly noisy.

Good luck!

Comment: I have a program called "SmartDefrag" in the C:\MyPrograms directory. That's the directory I made for the third-party programs I acquire. But SmartDefrag is not running and is not listed in Startup. I run Carbonite and Second Copy.

Comment: Matthew, I think I'll need to ask the tech next time he's here to fix something and I'll have him do what recommended.